# Fetching the data from google analytics to know how many users are accessing the application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, google-analytics

I develop a java application with spring. By the help of  google analytics i want to know how to display user log information like how many users are accessing that application.For that i have a code to display all  google analytics  information as below.

```
final String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
       Long userId = null;   
        if ( zerpSession != null ) {            
                userId = zerpSession.getUserId();

        }



   GoogleAnalytics ga = new GoogleAnalytics("UA-5555555555-1");
        DefaultRequest req = new DefaultRequest() ;

        if (userId != null) {
            req.userId(userId.toString());
        }

        ga.setDefaultRequest(req);

        ga.postAsync(new RequestProvider() {
            public GoogleAnalyticsRequest getRequest() {
                return new PageViewHit(requestURI, "URL Request");
            }
        });
```

Here i am not able to to understand that from where to get user Info.
I fetch that user id from the session. I am trying to check in  google analytics it is showing Zero users are accessing your application. Please help me for  that.

Comment: Please answer to my question